# How can I install XBMC Gotham?

Tags: software-installation, xbmc

I wanna install XBMC Gotham (not a newer or older version!!!) on Lubuntu 15.04, without manually compiling it. How can I do that?

Comment: Any reason why the installation from [universe repository](http://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=vivid&keywords=xbmc) (`sudo apt-get install xbmc`) does not install xbmc 13.2. on your system?

Comment: When I did that it a few months ago it was installing the new Kodi, but now it is install XBMC Gotham fine! Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Version 31.2 Gotham is in the [Ubuntu Universe](http://packages.ubuntu.com/vivid/xbmc) repositories:

```
% apt-cache policy xbmc
xbmc:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2:13.2+dfsg1-4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2:13.2+dfsg1-4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ vivid/universe i386 Packages
```

Therefore install via

```
sudo apt-get install xbmc
```

---

Check, that universe is active in <kbd>Software & Updates</kbd>

[image]